# F# string building

Tags: string, f#

I want to do this C# code in F#

```
  string[] a = new string[5];
    string b = string.Empty;
    a[0] = "Line 1";
    a[2] = "Line 2";

    foreach (string c in a)
    {
        b = c + Environment.NewLine;
    }
```

Comment: Are you sure that's what you want to do and not b += c + E.nl?

Comment: C'mon, why this is down voted?

Comment: +1: No reason a legitimate question should have been down voted.

Comment: Agreed. Although I suspect that Will Dean is right and there is a typo in the original question. That may be the reason for the down votes.

Comment: It was down-voted twice, so it's not only Will(if he down-voted at all). And typo is hardly a reason for down-vote.

Comment: Sorry I didn't mean to imply that Will down voted nor that typos were justification for down votes.

Comment: @Sunny: its not required to initialize all of the elements before using them, and a NullReferenceException does not occur by concatting null strings together.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Its a lot better to use the built-in String.Join method than rolling your own function based on repeated string concatting. Here's the code in F#:

```
open System
let a = [| "Line 1"; null; "Line 2"; null; null;|] 
let b = String.Join(Environment.NewLine, a)
```

Answer (score 2):

The '^' operator concatenates two strings.  Also, '+' is overloaded so it can work on strings.  But using a StringBuilder or Join is a better strategy for this.

Answer (score 2):

You can use F#'s `concat` function from `System` module, like this:

```
let a = [| "Line 1"; null; "Line 2"; null; null;|] 
let b = String.concat System.Environment.NewLine a
```

(you should not import `System` namespace to avoid name conflict between F#'s `String module` and .NET's `String class`)